# Where can "chargeabilities" be hyphenated?

Tags: spelling, hyphens

Where can I hyphenate (split at the end of the line; GB English) the words `chargeabilities` and `chargeability`? [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) does not know the words at all and [ushuaia](http://www.ushuaia.pl/hyphen/?ln=en) hyphenates `chargeab•il•it•ies`, which is not in accordance with my pronunciation of the word, but possibly I got that wrong because I am no native speaker but an ELL.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabification): "In some languages, the spoken syllables are also the basis of syllabification in writing. However, possibly due to the weak correspondence between sounds and letters in the spelling of modern English, written syllabification in English is based mostly on etymological or morphological instead of phonetic principles"

Comment: BTW, how did you get [chargeab•il•it•ies] on ushuaia? I think you might have chosen the wrong language, because the algorithm used by TeX is quite good, afaik.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: I chose "English (GB)", indeed "English (US)" gives `charge•abil•i•ties`, but I need to get it in UK-English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we can split the word at ***any*** syllable split. So, in your case, you can split the word at *any* 'dot' mentioned in dictionaries.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chargeability) has an entry for this word. You may 'click' on 'syllable' or may look a bit down on the page where it's mentioned *(under 'Related Forms')*.

Let's try it!

> The following tables provides a very general guide to possible ***chargea-
> bilities*** of materials. One reason that in-situ chargeabilities tend to appear 
> lower than laboratory values is that large volumes of mixed materials are 
>  involved in field measurements.

Comment: From Dictionary.com (thanks for the link!) I get `charge·a·ble` as well as `/ˈtʃɑr dʒə bəl/`, i.e. `charge-a-ble` vs. `char-gea-ble`, thus I am still confused.

Comment: You did not look down - *charge·a·bil·i·ty*